# redirect JMS messages based on a property in message using flume

Tags: hadoop, jms, flume, cloudera-cdh

We have configured Flume to read JMS messages from a system and this is working fine.

Now I would like to read message and redirect it to a multiple locations based on a property in the message.

Example:
If my TextMessage looks like: TextMessage ={Header={....} Properties ={type = {String:dest1}....}

I want to redirect this message to /path/to/base/dir/dest1

similarly if my message TextMessage ={Header={....} Properties ={type = {String:dest2}....}

my dest should be /path/to/base/dir/dest2

I'm not sure whether this can be achieved by using interceptors. If yes pls direct me

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to define a flow multiplexer.

Comment: I'm very new to Flume and JMS. Could you please direct me to flume multiplexing example or on defining a multiplexer to redirect based on message property